# CollectionType of EntityType Symfony Forms

Tags: php, forms, symfony

It is even possible to make ?

```
->add('product', CollectionType::class, [
      'entry_type'    => EntityType::class, array(
        'data' => $options['product'],
        'placeholder' => 'Wybierz klienta',
        'multiple' => true,
        'class' => Products::class,
        'attr' => ['class' => 'chosen-select','data-placeholder'=>'Wybierz produkt'],
        'choice_label' => function ($product) {
            return  ''.$product->getJson()["products"]["name"] .' | Stan Magazynowy: '.$product->getJson()["products"]["stock"].'';
          },
      'label' => 'Wybierz produkty'

      ),
      'entry_options' => [
          'label' => 'Value',
      ],
      'label'        => 'Add, move, remove values and press Submit.',
      'allow_add'    => true,
      'allow_delete' => true,
      'prototype'    => true,
      'required'     => false,
      'attr'         => [
          'class' => 'my-selector',
      ],
  ])
```

I'll try to add chosen list of Products::class in CollectiontType, if some one wanna add product to new order, can add new EntityType and select product, and after submit i`ll handle this as array and save it to order.

If someone has another idea how to add products to form with quantity and then post it to array, please free to write :)

Comment: This gives me a error:    The option "0" does not exist.

Comment: The `CollectionType` is typically expecting a collection of structured `FormTypes`, This is because the desired form elements to be included are defined in it, including those that are an entity. Your Data Model (`class`) should hold the `array` value. Have a look at [How to Embed a Collection of Forms](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html)

Comment: yeah and better way is just i.e. post got tags, so normal is to create form post and form tag and if you wanna add tags in post it is better way to just add collection type of tags forms with entitystype which is inside tags form - and it works, correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not the best way to do that.
You just have to add CollectionType to the FormType and update you ProductType class to handle if this is selected or not. May be you have to create a custom formtype for products for order only :-/ . All hard work are on the javascript side

Comment: yeah i did it, SearchProductsType, and i attach it to CollectionType in OrdersType and it works fine.